# Meaning of $get('0')?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I just upgraded to jQuery 1.12 from an older version. I'm going through the code, trying to resolve breaking changes.

One such change is occurring in the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    Sys.Application.add_unload(applciationUnloadHandler);
    function applciationUnloadHandler() {
        var contactDropDown = $get('0');
        createCookie('NewProgram_ContactID_Cookie', contactDropDown.value, null);
    }
});
```

This code fails because `$get('0')` returns `null`.

But I really don't understand what this is supposed to be doing. I don't see `$get()` defined anywhere. I can see from looking at the code behind that the `'0'` argument represents a contact ID, but I can't see what the code is supposed to be doing.

Comment: Why have you tagged this [tag:c#]?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/bb397717.aspx). I think it's the correct docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$get` is a shortcut function for `Sys.UI.DomElement.getElementById`

> The $get method provides a shortcut to the getElementById method of the Sys.UI.DomElement class.

[Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397706(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

`$get` is defined in the ASP.NET AJAX Client Side Library that should be included if you are using a ScriptManager.

Comment: Ok. Is there any way you could say what it does, or where it's documented? I wasn't able to find what I needed by Googling.

Comment: It's basically a `querySelector`. It is finding an element. The first argument is ID I believe.